# HTML tag does not open debugging ipad with safari

Tags: ios, css, ipad, debugging, safari

I'm trying to debug with Safari a current website as you can connect a macbook to your ipad. The only issue I'm encountering is that once inspecting the tags cannot be opened, so I cannot check the content. This is what I get if I want to open wrapper for example:

[image]

I click it but it does not open, so you cannot see the content and therefore its pretty useless. Has somebody encountered this issue?

Safari version: 6.0.5

Mac OS: 10.7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading Max OS to OS Mavericks did the trick!